# How to get Uniform Height for CollectionView Cell for Dynamic Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection View with Dynamic Cell.

I am finding the height of Cell a/c to the Text Supplied as:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CGFloat cellWidth = (self.mCollectionView.frame.size.width-7)/7;

CGFloat hegiht = [calendar getTheSizeForText:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] toFitInWidth:cellWidth];


return CGSizeMake(cellWidth,
                  hegiht) ;
 }
```

//FInding Height

```
   + (CGFloat)getTheSizeForText:(NSString *)text toFitInWidth:(CGFloat)width
{

CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width-2*kPadding, 999)
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]}
                                     context:nil];

CGFloat cellHeight = textRect.size.height+10+21 ; //5 top padding 5  
     bottom 21 is the height of another label which is fied

return cellHeight;
}
```

Now when I run my app I am getting Screen as this:

[image]

My Cell height is not Uniform. What is the best way to get Uniform height.